# Does randomly adding hand-engineered features increase the CNN's sample efficiency/performance?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, feature-engineering, sample-efficiency

It is a known fact that preprocessing images using CV techniques will improve CNN performance (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23478399)).

But what happens when you feed in the entire image and the filtered image randomly to the network? Would the Neural Network learn to focus on the relevant aspects of an unfiltered image?

If yes, please explain how randomly processed images improve the CNN's performance/sample efficiency.

Comment: The question in the title seems to be different and more general than the question in the body of your post. Could you please clarify what your main question is here and how the two questions are related?

Comment: @nbro Thank you. Made the corrections.

Comment: Ok, it's still not clear to me whether you're talking about "data augmentation", i.e. where you artificially generate data by applying some transformations to your original data so that to increase the size of your dataset. Then you would feed either the original images or some transformed image. So, would your question be: "Why is data augmentation useful?". If yes, please, edit your post to reformulate the question by mentioning "data augmentation" specifically.

Comment: To me, what's still confusing in your post is this sentence: "when you feed in the entire image and the filtered image randomly to the network". It's not clear whether you're considering the case where you feed 2 images to the neural network each time: one is the original one and the other is the transformed one (chosen randomly??).